# Trouble proving$\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{S\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ is T(n-1)

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $x_{n+1}$ is an additional observation, which is distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and is independent of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, also $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I have tried to change the form of  $\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{S\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$, in order to get N(0,1) on top and Chi-square at the bottom, however, my effort went nowhere. $\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{S\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$=$\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{\sigma\sqrt\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$

Got stuck at dealing with $\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{\sigma\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$

Can anyone help to take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
X_{n+1}-\bar{X}\sim N(0, \sigma^2(1+n^{-1}))
$$
where the second parameter is variance since a linear combination of independent normals is normally distributed. It follows that
$$
Z=\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{\sigma\sqrt{1+n^{-1}}}\sim N(0, 1).
$$
Next if $S^2$ denotes the sample variance of $X_{1}, \dotsc, X_n$, we have that
$$
W=\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi ^2_{(n-1)}
$$
and further $Z$ is independent of $W$ whence
$$
T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{W/n-1}}=\frac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}}{S\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\sim t_{(n-1)}
$$
as desired.